# eID Middleware: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java

I am making an application where I need to retrieve information from eID's. I have downloaded the Belgium Identity Card SDK and added beid35libJava.jar as external JAR to my project. Now I am trying to load the library beid35libJava_Wrapper.dll through

```
System.loadLibrary("beid35libJava_Wrapper");
```

but I get the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Emmelie\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Registratietool\beid35libJava_Wrapper.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1732)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at Registratietool.main(Registratietool.java:51)
```

All the libraries and jar-files are in the same folder, namely the project folder. I can't figure out where the error comes from. If someone could help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the old SDK 3.5 to start a new java-project.

For a java based project I would recommend using eid-commons:
it is a lot easier to use and up to date.
You can find it at:
http://code.google.com/p/commons-eid/